# Return the enumeration instead of the index

Tags: c++, enums

I have a simple class that uses an enum for "status". When I use the `getStatus` member function, it does indeed return "Busy" but when I print the value, it shows a "1". How can I print "Busy" instead of 1?

http://codepad.org/9NDlxxyU demonstration

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Status{Idle, Busy};
class text
{
public:
    void SetStatus(Status s);
    Status getStatus();
private:
    Status s;       
};
void text::SetStatus(Status s)
{
    this->s = s;
}
Status text::getStatus()
{
    return this->s;
}

int main()
{
    text myText;
    myText.SetStatus(Busy);
    cout << myText.getStatus() << endl; //outputs 1, should output "Busy"
}
```

Comment: No, @Nicol, that's not a duplicate at all. The answer to that question is to call the enum's `ToString` method, which only .Net enums have, not native C++ enums.

Comment: It is _not_ a duplicate. OP is not asking for an 'automatic' way for any enum. He wants to know _what should be done_ to get _this_ enum displayed as desired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fully working edit is live here: **http://ideone.com/WFo4g**

Add:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Status status)
{
    switch (status)
    {
        case Idle: return os << "Idle";
        case Busy: return os << "Busy";
        default:   return os << "Status:" << status;
    }

    return os << "<error>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't without further work. `Busy` is just an identifier that exists at compile time for your convenience. During compilation, the compiler replaces all occurencies of it with the real value `1`.

To make it work like you want, you'll need an extra array or mapping from the enum value to a string that depicts the enum identifier.

Comment: oh that's lame, kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: Not at all.  The purpose is to prevent magic values and typos.  Same reason we have variables.