# Converting int to enum

Tags: c++

I have an `object` and one of its properties is `object.type` when I return `object.type` it returns `2` but I would rather it return the enumeration of `2` for example `soft`

```
enum type {
    hard = 0,
    brittle,
    soft
};
```

Comment: You need to provide some code to elaborate on what you're talking about. At the very least the class that `object` is an instance of and the `enum` you're trying to use.

Comment: Please provide a **complete**, **minimal** program that demonstrates the problem you are having. See http://sscce.org for more info.

Comment: what's the type of object.type? why don't you use the enum?

Comment: @yi_H it is of type enum

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return the enumeration instead of the index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922632/return-the-enumeration-instead-of-the-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual easiest (and correct) way of doing it may be using a `std::map` for that:

```
enum MyEnum {A, B, C};

std::map<MyEnum, std::string> myEnumDesc;
MyEnumDesc[A] = "A";
...

// Then
std::cout << myEnumDesc[object.type] << std::endl;
```

(if `type` is of type `MyEnum`). There are other alternatives, more or less portable, but you're safe with this.

Answer (score 0):

an enum is an int, not a string.

if `soft` is what you're calling your enum member, then `soft` is like a const int, and it can have the value 3.

you could have a map (stl, http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) with int as key and string as value, and then map the values to the names. and then you could have a method in your class instead of a property (e.g. `getTypeName`), and that method could return the string name corresponding to the current value of type, instead of the enum constant itself.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for streaming operators? (Obviously, this is portable code)

See this live here: http://ideone.com/eRniK

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const type v)
{
    switch (v)
    {
        case soft: return os << "soft";
        case brittle: return os << "brittle";
        case hard: return os << "hard";
        default:   return os << "#" << v;
    }

    return os << "<error>";
}
```

Now

```
type x = hard;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
```

Will print 'hard'

Answer (score -3):

Please do NOT use enum.

You can go to  http://well-spun.co.uk/code_templates/enums.php

and use the compiler to make sure that you do things right.

Comment: Sorry can't condone it. Looks like FUD as well as obsolete in the light of c++11 enum classes

Comment: Why should someone not use enums?